# React Flow showing Cannot resolve module error for create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Good day.

I am trying to setup React with Flow for type checking but I can't seem to be having any luck so far. I can't really find an answer anywhere as of yet.

I followed the Flow installation instructions:
I installed flow using `npm i flow-bin`, then ran `npm run flow init` which will create a `.flowconfig` file and I am using create-react-app so according to the documentation that was it.

In the `.flowconfig` under [options] i set all to `all=true` for Flow to check every file, and excluded files under the `node_modules` folder since there are about more than 45500 files in there and I want to only type check files under `/src`, therefore my `.flowconfig` file is like this:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*

[include]
.*/src/.*

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
all=true

[strict]
```

Then on my component i have:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Languagecurrency.scss";
import { Modal } from "antd";
import { useStoreActions, useStoreState } from "easy-peasy";
```

Then when i run npm run flow, i get  the following errors:

```
Error ----------------------------------src/components/Button/Button.js:3:8

Cannot resolve module ./Button.scss.

     1| 
     2| import * as React from "react";
     3| import "./Button.scss";
     4| import { Modal } from "antd";
     5| import { useStoreActions, useStoreState } from "easy-peasy";
     6|
     7| type Props = {

Error ----------------------------------src/components/Button/Button.js:4:8

Cannot resolve module antd.

     1| 
     2| import * as React from "react";
     3| import "./Button.scss";
     4| import { Modal } from "antd";
     5| import { useStoreActions, useStoreState } from "easy-peasy";
     6|
     7| type Props = {

Error ----------------------------------src/components/Button/Button.js:5:8

Cannot resolve module easy-peasy.

     1| 
     2| import * as React from "react";
     3| import "./Button.scss";
     4| import { Modal } from "antd";
     5| import { useStoreActions, useStoreState } from "easy-peasy";
     6|
     7| type Props = {
```

Please help

Thank you in advance

These are all the errors i get

```
Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- scripts/class_component.js:3:8

Cannot resolve module ./comp_name.scss.

     1| 
     2| import * as React from "react";
     3| import './comp_name.scss';
     4|
     5| class comp_name extends React.Component<{}> {
     6|   state = {};


Error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- scripts/class_component.js:6:11

Cannot extend React.Component [1] with comp_name because object literal [2] is incompatible with undefined [3] in
property state.

     scripts/class_component.js
      3| import './comp_name.scss';
      4|
 [1]  5| class comp_name extends React.Component<{}> {
 [2]  6|   state = {};
      7|   render() {
      8|     return <>comp_name component</>;
      9|   }

     ../../../../AppData/Local/Temp/flow/flowlib_1c6c9ec/react.js
 [3] 26| declare class React$Component<Props, State = void> {


Error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- scripts/component_index.js:1:25

Cannot resolve module ./comp_name.

     1| export { default } from "./comp_name";
     2|


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ scripts/functional_component.js:3:8

Cannot resolve module ./comp_name.scss.

     1| 
     2| import * as React from "react";
     3| import './comp_name.scss';
     4|
     5| const comp_name = () => {
     6|   return <>comp_name component</>;


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- scripts/system_routes.js:26:11

Cannot resolve name result.

     23|       };
     24|       clean.forEach(val => {
     25|         if (val.includes("path")) {
     26|           result = val.split("=");
     27|           data.path = result[1].replace(/"/g, "");
     28|         }
     29|         if (val.includes("component")) {


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- scripts/system_routes.js:30:11

Cannot resolve name result.

     27|           data.path = result[1].replace(/"/g, "");
     28|         }
     29|         if (val.includes("component")) {
     30|           result = val.split("=");
     31|           data.component = result[1].replace(/{|}/g, "");
     32|         }
     33|       });


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- scripts/system_routes.js:38:17

Could not decide which case to select, since case 2 [1] may work but if it doesn't case 3 [2] looks promising too. To
fix add a type annotation to unknown element type of empty array [3].

        scripts/system_routes.js
    [3]  14|   let routes = [];
           :
         35|     }
         36|   });
         37|
         38|   console.table(routes)
         39| } catch (err) {
         40|   console.error(err);
         41| }

        ../../../../AppData/Local/Temp/flow/flowlib_1c6c9ec/core.js
 [1][2] 928|     table(tabularData: { [key: string]: any, ... } | Array<{ [key: string]: any, ... }> | Array<Array<any>>): void,


Error --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/App.js:2:8

Cannot resolve module ./App.scss.

     1| import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
     2| import "./App.scss";
     3| import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
     4|
     5| /** Pages **/


Error -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/App.js:3:31

Cannot resolve module react-router-dom.

     1| import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
     2| import "./App.scss";
     3| import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
     4|
     5| /** Pages **/
     6| import Home from "./pages/landing-pages/home/Home";


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/App.js:17:31

Cannot resolve module easy-peasy.

     14| import Dateselection from "./pages/landing-pages/dateselection/Dateselection";
     15| import Daterangeselection from "./pages/landing-pages/daterangeselection/Daterangeselection";
     16| import Productselection from "./pages/landing-pages/product-selection/Productselection";
     17| import { useStoreState } from "easy-peasy";
     18|
     19| function App() {
     20|   const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(


Error --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/App.test.js:2:24

Cannot resolve module @testing-library/react.

     1| import React from 'react';
     2| import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
     3| import App from './App';
     4|
     5| test('renders learn react link', () => {


Error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/App.test.js:5:1

Cannot resolve name test.

     2| import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
     3| import App from './App';
     4|
     5| test('renders learn react link', () => {
     6|   const { getByText } = render(<App />);
     7|   const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
     8|   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();


Error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/App.test.js:8:3

Cannot resolve name expect.

      5| test('renders learn react link', () => {
      6|   const { getByText } = render(<App />);
      7|   const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
      8|   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
      9| });
     10|


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ src/components/Button/Button.js:3:8

Cannot resolve module ./Button.scss.

     1| 
     2| import * as React from "react";
     3| import "./Button.scss";
     4| import Icons from "../Icons";
     5|
     6| type Props = {


Error -------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Checkbox/Checkbox.js:2:8

Cannot resolve module ./Checkbox.scss.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import "./Checkbox.scss";
     3| import { useState } from "react";
     4|
     5| const Checkbox = (props) => {


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Checkbox/Checkbox.js:5:19

Missing type annotation for props.

     2| import "./Checkbox.scss";
     3| import { useState } from "react";
     4|
     5| const Checkbox = (props) => {
     6|   const { children, type, checked, value, styles, onChange, name, id } = props;
     7|   const [state, setState] = useState(checked);
     8|


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/CustomSelect/CustomSelect.js:2:20

Cannot resolve module react-select.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import Select from "react-select";
     3|
     4| const CustomSelect = ({
     5|   onChange,


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/CustomSelect/CustomSelect.js:4:23

Missing type annotation for destructuring.

      1| import React from "react";
      2| import Select from "react-select";
      3|
      4| const CustomSelect = ({
      5|   onChange,
      6|   onInputChange,
      7|   name,
      8|   placeholder,
      9|   value,
     10|   options,
     11| }) => {
     12|   const dot = (color = "#bed523") => ({
     13|     alignItems: "center",
     14|     display: "flex",


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ src/components/Drawer/Drawer.js:2:8

Cannot resolve module ./Drawer.scss.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import "./Drawer.scss";
     3| import { Drawer } from "antd";
     4| import "antd/dist/antd.css";
     5| import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Drawer/Drawer.js:3:24

Cannot resolve module antd.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import "./Drawer.scss";
     3| import { Drawer } from "antd";
     4| import "antd/dist/antd.css";
     5| import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
     6| import Icons from "../Icons";


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ src/components/Drawer/Drawer.js:4:8

Cannot resolve module antd/dist/antd.css.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import "./Drawer.scss";
     3| import { Drawer } from "antd";
     4| import "antd/dist/antd.css";
     5| import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
     6| import Icons from "../Icons";
     7| import { useStoreActions } from "easy-peasy";


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Drawer/Drawer.js:5:22

Cannot resolve module react-router-dom.

     2| import "./Drawer.scss";
     3| import { Drawer } from "antd";
     4| import "antd/dist/antd.css";
     5| import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
     6| import Icons from "../Icons";
     7| import { useStoreActions } from "easy-peasy";
     8|


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Drawer/Drawer.js:7:33

Cannot resolve module easy-peasy.

      4| import "antd/dist/antd.css";
      5| import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
      6| import Icons from "../Icons";
      7| import { useStoreActions } from "easy-peasy";
      8|
      9| const Customdrawer = ({ openDrawer, onCloseDrawer }) => {
     10|   const makeChange = useStoreActions((actions) => actions.System.makeChange);


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Drawer/Drawer.js:9:23

Missing type annotation for destructuring.

      6| import Icons from "../Icons";
      7| import { useStoreActions } from "easy-peasy";
      8|
      9| const Customdrawer = ({ openDrawer, onCloseDrawer }) => {
     10|   const makeChange = useStoreActions((actions) => actions.System.makeChange);
     11|
     12|   const langCurr = () => {


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.js:2:43

Cannot resolve module react-bootstrap.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import { Dropdown as ReactDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
     3| import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
     4| import "./Dropdown.scss";
     5| import Checkbox from "../Checkbox";


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.js:3:22

Cannot resolve module react-router-dom.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import { Dropdown as ReactDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
     3| import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
     4| import "./Dropdown.scss";
     5| import Checkbox from "../Checkbox";
     6| import Icons from "../Icons";


Error -------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.js:4:8

Cannot resolve module ./Dropdown.scss.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import { Dropdown as ReactDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
     3| import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
     4| import "./Dropdown.scss";
     5| import Checkbox from "../Checkbox";
     6| import Icons from "../Icons";
     7|


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.js:8:19

Missing type annotation for destructuring.

      5| import Checkbox from "../Checkbox";
      6| import Icons from "../Icons";
      7|
      8| const Dropdown = ({ links, onCheckbox }) => {
      9|   const CustomToggle = React.forwardRef(({ children, onClick }, ref) => (
     10|     <button
     11|       type="button"


Error ---------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Fatalerror/Fatalerror.js:2:8

Cannot resolve module ./Fatalerror.scss.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import './Fatalerror.scss';
     3| import fatal_error from '../../assets/images/fatal-error.png'
     4|
     5| const Fatalerror = ({onReload}) => {


Error --------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Fatalerror/Fatalerror.js:5:21

Missing type annotation for destructuring.

     2| import './Fatalerror.scss';
     3| import fatal_error from '../../assets/images/fatal-error.png'
     4|
     5| const Fatalerror = ({onReload}) => {
     6|   return <>
     7|   <div className="fatal-error-container">
     8|     <div className="fatal-error-image">


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ src/components/Footer/Footer.js:2:8

Cannot resolve module ./Footer.scss.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import "./Footer.scss";
     3| import logo from "../../assets/images/esim2go_logo.svg";
     4|
     5| const Footer = () => {


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ src/components/Header/Header.js:2:8

Cannot resolve module ./Header.scss.

     1| import React, { useState } from "react";
     2| import "./Header.scss";
     3| import logo from "../../assets/images/esim2go_logo.svg";
     4| import notification_icon from "../../assets/images/notification_icon.svg";
     5| import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Header/Header.js:5:22

Cannot resolve module react-router-dom.

     2| import "./Header.scss";
     3| import logo from "../../assets/images/esim2go_logo.svg";
     4| import notification_icon from "../../assets/images/notification_icon.svg";
     5| import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
     6| import ReactCountryFlag from "react-country-flag";
     7| import Icons from "../Icons";
     8| import Drawer from "../Drawer";


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Header/Header.js:6:30

Cannot resolve module react-country-flag.

     3| import logo from "../../assets/images/esim2go_logo.svg";
     4| import notification_icon from "../../assets/images/notification_icon.svg";
     5| import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
     6| import ReactCountryFlag from "react-country-flag";
     7| import Icons from "../Icons";
     8| import Drawer from "../Drawer";
     9| import Languagecurrency from "../modals/language-currency/Languagecurrency";


Error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Header/Header.js:10:33

Cannot resolve module easy-peasy.

      7| import Icons from "../Icons";
      8| import Drawer from "../Drawer";
      9| import Languagecurrency from "../modals/language-currency/Languagecurrency";
     10| import { useStoreActions } from "easy-peasy";
     11|
     12| const Header = () => {
     13|   const [searchOpen, setSearchOpen] = useState(false);


Error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Header/Header.js:34:17

Cannot call searchInput.focus because property focus is missing in null [1].

     src/components/Header/Header.js
       31|
       32|   const searchInputFocus = () => {
       33|     const searchInput = document.getElementById("global-search");
       34|     searchInput.focus();
       35|   };
       36|
       37|   const langCurr = () => {

     ../../../../AppData/Local/Temp/flow/flowlib_1c6c9ec/dom.js
 [1] 1250|   getElementById(elementId: string): HTMLElement | null;


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Icons/Check.js:3:16

Missing type annotation for destructuring.

     1| import React from "react";
     2|
     3| const Check = ({ height = 24, width = 24 }) => (
     4|   <svg
     5|     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     6|     height={height}


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Icons/Icons.js:7:16

Missing type annotation for destructuring.

      4| import Check from "./Check";
      5| import Spinner from "./Spinner";
      6|
      7| const Icons = ({ icon, className = "" }) => {
      8|
      9|   const container = (icon) => {
     10|     let svg = "";


Error -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Input/Input.js:2:8

Cannot resolve module ./Input.scss.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import "./Input.scss";
     3|
     4| const Input = ({
     5|   type = "text",


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Input/Input.js:4:16

Missing type annotation for destructuring.

      1| import React from "react";
      2| import "./Input.scss";
      3|
      4| const Input = ({
      5|   type = "text",
      6|   name = "",
      7|   className,
      8|   placeholder = "",
      9|   id = "",
     10|   onKeyUp,
     11|   onChange,
     12| }) => {
     13|   const keyUp = (e) => {
     14|     const target = e.target
     15|     if (target.value.trim().length !== 0) {


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------ src/components/Notification/Notification.js:2:8

Cannot resolve module ./Notification.scss.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import "./Notification.scss";
     3| import { notification } from "antd";
     4|
     5| const Notification = (type, message, header = "") => {


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Notification/Notification.js:3:30

Cannot resolve module antd.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import "./Notification.scss";
     3| import { notification } from "antd";
     4|
     5| const Notification = (type, message, header = "") => {
     6|   notification[type]({


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Notification/Notification.js:5:23

Missing type annotation for type.

     2| import "./Notification.scss";
     3| import { notification } from "antd";
     4|
     5| const Notification = (type, message, header = "") => {
     6|   notification[type]({
     7|     top: 62,
     8|     message: header !== "" ? header : null,


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Notification/Notification.js:5:29

Missing type annotation for message.

     2| import "./Notification.scss";
     3| import { notification } from "antd";
     4|
     5| const Notification = (type, message, header = "") => {
     6|   notification[type]({
     7|     top: 62,
     8|     message: header !== "" ? header : null,


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/Notification/Notification.js:5:38

Missing type annotation for header.

     2| import "./Notification.scss";
     3| import { notification } from "antd";
     4|
     5| const Notification = (type, message, header = "") => {
     6|   notification[type]({
     7|     top: 62,
     8|     message: header !== "" ? header : null,


Error ------------------------------------------------------------------------ src/components/PageStage/PageStage.js:2:8

Cannot resolve module ./PageStage.scss.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import './PageStage.scss';
     3|
     4| const PageStage = ({ stage }) => {
     5|   return (


Error ----------------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/PageStage/PageStage.js:4:20

Missing type annotation for destructuring.

     1| import React from "react";
     2| import './PageStage.scss';
     3|
     4| const PageStage = ({ stage }) => {
     5|   return (
     6|     <>
     7|       <div className="page-stage">


Error -------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/ProductPackage/ProductPackage.js:2:8

Cannot resolve module ./ProductPackage.scss.

     1| import React, { useState } from "react";
     2| import "./ProductPackage.scss";
     3| import ReactCountryFlag from "react-country-flag";
     4| import Packagemoreinfo from "../modals/package-moreinfo/Packagemoreinfo";
     5|


Error ------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/ProductPackage/ProductPackage.js:3:30

Cannot resolve module react-country-flag.

     1| import React, { useState } from "react";
     2| import "./ProductPackage.scss";
     3| import ReactCountryFlag from "react-country-flag";
     4| import Packagemoreinfo from "../modals/package-moreinfo/Packagemoreinfo";
     5|
     6| const ProductPackage = ({ data }) => {


Error ------------------------------------------------------------- src/components/ProductPackage/ProductPackage.js:6:25

Missing type annotation for destructuring.

     3| import ReactCountryFlag from "react-country-flag";
     4| import Packagemoreinfo from "../modals/package-moreinfo/Packagemoreinfo";
     5|
     6| const ProductPackage = ({ data }) => {
     7|   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
     8|
     9|   const showModal = () => {
```